# How to omit useless whitespace Text element from parsed XML using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, ram

I’m working on an application that uses Nokogiri to ingest XML from a large number of small XML files, and a lot of memory is consumed by whitespace in those files, in the form of text nodes whose values are mostly whitespace-only, e.g. `”   \n”`. Is there a convenient solution already available for this? I tried deleting all text elements containing only whitespace, but it took a considerable amount of time at runtime. I’m now thinking of processing the text that is read from the files and removing the whitespace (possibly by simply calling strip on all the lines), before passing the text into the parser. What do you think? Is there a better way? The software is sometimes run on appliances with limited RAM and the memory savings would be helpful.

Comment: I've added this step to the XML parsing:

```
xml_text = File.readlines(filespec).map(&:strip).join
```

and am seeing a savings of 27 MB (> 700,000 Text elements). Is there any risk with this strategy? Is there legal XML for which joining lines without whitespace delimiting them would result in an error?

Comment: Did you try `NOBLANKS` parse option? (https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#parse-options)